# Images do not show up in build of App IONIC 2

Tags: android, ios, image, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 and I am having some problems with images in my app.
Searching online I understood that the images must be put in the /src/assets folder inside the app. (*correct?*)

The images work fine using `ionic serve` and `ionic lab` commands but in the simulated devices or using Ionic View on an iPad they do not show up!

I reference the images in the code with:

```
<img src="../assets/img/ringing.png" class="circle_icons">
```

How can I solve this?

(Down are some screenshot of the problem)

[Screenshot of the simulator with problems displaying images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg7bm.png)

[Screenshot of the `ionic serve` without problems displaying images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVflX.png)

Answer (score 2):

After placing the images in your assets folder just reference them like this.

```
<img src="assets/images/MiTUCson-quick-search.png" alt="Consulta Rapida"
```

Comment: Did not worked.
If I try to do that, when I run in the simulator it still doesn't render the image and inside the image outline the Consulta Rapida text appears.

Comment: did you replace the image src with your images? or just copy paste what i copied ?

Comment: it should work with ony placing <img src="assets/img/ringing.png" class="circle_icons">

Comment: I did substitute the name.